# MongoDB, find() result, convert to json

Tags: json, mongodb

```
email: {"email":"aaa@bbb.eu"}
{ _mongooseOptions: {},
  mongooseCollection:
   { collection:
      { db: [Object],
        collectionName: 'parties',
        internalHint: null,
        opts: {},
        slaveOk: false,
        serializeFunctions: false,
        raw: false,
        pkFactory: [Object],
        serverCapabilities: undefined },
     opts: { bufferCommands: true, capped: false },
     name: 'parties',
     conn:
      { base: [Object],
        collections: [Object],
        models: [Object],
        replica: false,
        hosts: null,
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 27017,
        user: undefined,
        pass: undefined,
        name: 'pluserDB',
        options: [Object],
        otherDbs: [],
        _readyState: 1,
        _closeCalled: false,
        _hasOpened: true,
        _listening: true,
        _events: {},
        db: [Object] },
     queue: [],
     buffer: false },
  model:
   { [Function: model]
     base:
      { connections: [Object],
        plugins: [],
        models: [Object],
        modelSchemas: [Object],
        options: [Object] },
     modelName: 'Party',
     model: [Function: model],
     db:
      { base: [Object],
        collections: [Object],
        models: [Object],
        replica: false,
        hosts: null,
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 27017,
        user: undefined,
        pass: undefined,
        name: 'pluserDB',
        options: [Object],
        otherDbs: [],
        _readyState: 1,
        _closeCalled: false,
        _hasOpened: true,
        _listening: true,
        _events: {},
        db: [Object] },
     discriminators: undefined,
     schema:
      { paths: [Object],
        subpaths: {},
        virtuals: [Object],
        nested: {},
        inherits: {},
        callQueue: [],
        _indexes: [],
        methods: {},
        statics: {},
        tree: [Object],
        _requiredpaths: undefined,
        discriminatorMapping: undefined,
        _indexedpaths: undefined,
        options: [Object],
        _events: {} },
     options: undefined,
     collection:
      { collection: [Object],
        opts: [Object],
        name: 'parties',
        conn: [Object],
        queue: [],
        buffer: false } },
  op: 'find',
  options: {},
  _conditions: { email: '{"email":"aaa@bbb.eu"}' },
  _fields: { email: 1, _id: 0 },
  _update: undefined,
  _path: undefined,
  _distinct: undefined,
  _collection:
   { collection:
      { collection: [Object],
        opts: [Object],
        name: 'parties',
        conn: [Object],
        queue: [],
        buffer: false },
     collectionName: undefined },
  _traceFunction: undefined,
  _castError: null }
```

Please have a look at code below:

```
var parties = Party.find({ email: email }, { email: 1, _id: 0 });
```

this query returns 3 documents.
Now I want to send result and stringify these documents:

```
response.json(parties);
```

I get error here because `parties` contains circular references and does not just contain plain data I need here.

Question is:

How can I stringify result of `find()` method here?

Comment: Could you please add the response documents?

Comment: Added `parties` as a code snippet.

Comment: What is the platform you use? I really dont see what are you trying to do. Please show me the mongo shell response for Party.find().

Comment: > db.parties.find({email: "aaa@bbb.eu"}, {email:1, _id:0})
{ "email" : "aaa@bbb.eu" }
{ "email" : "aaa@bbb.eu" }
{ "email" : "aaa@bbb.eu" }
>

Comment: I need to convert such a result to json.

Comment: I use `express` as a server, it gets a `post` call and needs to provide data.

Comment: I think these can help you -- Node.js documentation for mongo find(): https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/queries.html, and a good totorial for express and mongo: http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/node-express-mongo/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92283/discussion-between-jacek-wojcik-and-balint-steinbach).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know what my mistake was.

`MongoDB` and it's shell is not the same as `Mongoose` API.

`find()` method needs different arguments for both.

The one I needed here is:

```
Party.find({ 'email': email }, 'email', function (err, parties) { response.json(parties)});
```

Comment: Where do you get the response variable? Why is that the one you needed?